# UEFI bootable usb on a MBR disk (Windows 10)

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-10

I am trying to install windows 10 from an EFI bootable usb I have. However, I get the error `Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks.`

I have read in some forums that a similar problem when installing with a bootable DVD can be fixed by changing the dvd format to SATA from the BIOS. I am unable to do that to my USB. 
So,

1. Is there anyway to change my EFI bootable USB to SATA?
2. If not, how do I reliably change my disk to GPT?
3. Will windows install after changing to GPT? (I am asking because I assume I will have to sacrifice the data on my disk to convert it to GPT)

Comment: What do you have on the disk currently?

Comment: I had some files on a non-OS partition of the disk. I do not mind losing them if its necessary. However, I want to be absolutely sure that converting my Disk to GPT will not mess things up more than they already are and I will be able to install windows successfully.

Comment: I'll look into how you can convert it without a working OS.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I fixed this problem as per snayob s comments:

- The problem was that I had *not* created my bootable USB correctly. 
  [This](http://bootableusb.net/install-windows-7-usb-drive-easy-way/) is a good link to create a bootable windows USB.
- Next, with CSM enabled in my BIOS (ASUS Z787 PRO), I could see 3 choices in the "BOOT options" :-

  - Hard Disk
  - KingstonDataTraveller
  - UEFI:KingstonDataTraveller

I selected option b which essentially boots windows using BIOS and *not* UEFI. 
BIOS option of windows installs on MBR disks.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer has UEFI firmware so you can enable CSM (BIOS support) in firmware. This varies from computer to computer so no detailed steps can be given.

Your UEFI bootable USB can be booted also using BIOS (if it was made the standard way - check if you have a \boot folder and bootmgr in root folder on USB).

On booting USB (after CSM enabled) select boot option for USB without UEFI.

Another way to go is restructure disk from MBR to GPT style. If you go this way - BACKUP YOUR USER FILES FIRST! (if possible make complete backup)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have CSM enabled and my bootable USB has the \boot folder and bootmgr. 
However, how do I "select boot option for USB without UEFI" ?

Comment: I think I see what you re saying. In my BIOS boot options there is a "KingstonDataTraveller" and a "UEFI:KingstonDataTraveller", so selecting the former would be what you re talking about. 
It does not work so I'm assuming my bootable usb is not  created correctly, but thanks for your instruction.

Comment: USB option should be listed when you select boot devices on initial boot (try F10 key - there must be prompt on cold boot - a key for entering setup and another key for device selection)

Comment: You can make USB BIOS bootable by making USB partition active (if it is not) (active = boot flag in gparted)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to change your EFI bootable USB to SATA.

To change your disk to GPT without data loss, you can use a tool called `gptgen`. You will need a working Windows installation to use the tool. I still strongly suggest that you backup your drive first in case it goes wrong. Some detailed information can be found [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk).